# Eloquent Many to Many select User without certain Roles

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So I have `User` & `Role` models with many-to-many relationship, I have 3 roles: `super`, `admin` and `moderator` with 4 users let's says: `John`, `Mike`, `James` and `Larry`.

`John` is a `super`, `Mike` has `admin` and `moderator` roles, `James` is an `admin` and `Larry` is a `moderator`. To displaying users who doesn't have certain roles I created this scope:

```
public function scopeDoesntHaveRoles($query, $roles = [], $column = 'id') {
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('roles')->orWhereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($roles, $column) {
        $q->whereNotIn($column, $roles);
    });
}
```

When I call `User::doesntHaveRoles([1])->lists('name', 'id')` to get users who doesn't have `super` role, it works and returns:

```
{"2":"Mike","3":"James","4":"Larry"}
```

But, when I trying to list users who doesn't have `admin` role `User::doesntHaveRoles([2])->lists('name', 'id')`,  yes `James` is not shown there but `Mike` is appeared while he is actually has `admin` role:

```
{"1":"John","2":"Mike","4":"Larry"}
```

I think it's because `Mike` is also has `moderator` role, do you see something wrong in my scope? or do you have other solutions?

Thanks

**Edit:**
Here is my pivot schema

```
Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

    $table->primary([
        'user_id', 'role_id'
    ]);
});
```

`User` model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_roles');
}
```

`Role` Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_roles');
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the schema of the pivot table between the `roles` and the `users` tables.If you follow the convention you should have a role_id column on which you want to call the `whereNotIn` method.

Comment: @shempignon It's just a basic pivot table, see edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `whereNotIn` instead of `whereDoesntHave`.

Given a `Role` stored in the variable `$role` you can get all users who don't have that role with:

```php
/* @var Role $role */
User::whereNotIn(function('id', $query) use ($role) {
    $query->select('user_id')
        ->from('user_roles')
        ->where('role_id', $role->id);
});
```

The inner query will return all IDs of users who has the given role. Using `whereNotIn` will return the opposite set of users. The folowing query will be created:

```sql
select *
from users
where user_id not in (
    select user_id
    from user_roles
    where role_id = ?
);
```

Now having a `Collection` of roles stored in `$roles` you can get all users who don't have any of that roles with:

```php
/* @var Collection|Role[] $roles */
User::whereNotIn(function('id', $query) use ($roles) {
    $query->select('user_id')
        ->from('user_roles')
        ->whereIn('role_id', $roles->pluck('id');
});
```

The inner select will return IDs of all users who has one of the roles in the collection. With `whereNotIn` you will again get the opposite result. You can also use an array of role-ids instead of `$roles->pluck('id')`.

The builder will create a query like

```sql
select *
from users
where user_id not in (
    select user_id
    from user_roles
    where role_id in (?, ?, ..)
);
```

Comment: Finally I got a brilliant solution, thanks @PaulSpiegel that's what I'm looking for.